# Query data from List<dynamic> which have Multiple type objects

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, dynamic

```
var student1 = new {name: "abc"};
var student2 = new {name: "efg"}
var department1 = new { name: "science", location= "ny"}
var department2 = new { name: "maths", location= "nj"}
var department3 = new { name: "social", location= "ny"}

List<dynamic> dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();

dynamicList.Add(student1);
dynamicList.Add(student2);
dynamicList.Add(department1);
dynamicList.Add(department2);
dynamicList.Add(department3);
```

Now I would like to get the count of total objects in dynamicList where location = "ny"

```
var total = dynamicList.Count(x=> (string)x.location == "ny");
```

**this is throwing exception as there is no definition for location.**

---

**Udpate:** Same LINQ query works when I have location property objects are firs tin the list.

```
    dynamicList.Add(department1);
    dynamicList.Add(department2);
    dynamicList.Add(department3);
    dynamicList.Add(student1);
    dynamicList.Add(student2);
 var total = dynamicList.Count(x=> (string)x.location == "ny");
```

This works with out any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally forget about LINQ and strong typing if you use `dynamic` types. The whole point of LINQ is that the types you are dealing with are known at compile time.

In order to test if a dynamic type has some property defined you will need to `try` and `catch` which obviously comes with the corresponding performance impact:

```
var total = dynamicList.Count(x =>
{
    try
    {
        return (string)x.location == "ny";
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This being said, if you are using dynamic types in your code, you are probably already accustomed to such impacts on the performance of your code so that won't be much of a big deal.

Comment: Well LINQ works when i have dynamic object with location property first in the list. If I forget LINQ what is the alternate with performance concerns

Comment: I have updated my answer to illustrate your other alternative with performance concerns. Obviously since you have opted for using `dynamic` types you already have such performance problems by design, so my illustrated solution won't impact you that much.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using is messy. At first you are using anonymous types inappropriately. Also, the `LINQ` is invented to deal with generic types i.e. the type parameters should be known at compile time to get benefits of `LINQ`.
Anyway, you can use the specialty of anonymous type, by which, their types are determined by property name, type and order. Thus, the type of

```
new { name = "", location= ""}
```

object is the same as the type of your `department` objects.

Here is the code you can use:

```
List<dynamic> dynamicList = new List<dynamic>
{
    new {name = "abc"},
    new {name = "efg"},
    new {name = "science", location= "ny"},
    new {name = "maths", location= "nj"},
    new {name = "social", location= "ny"},
};
var type = (new {name = "", location = ""}).GetType();
var methodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("OfType");
var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var total = (genericMethod.Invoke(null, new [] {dynamicList}) as IEnumerable<dynamic>)
            .Count(f => f.location == "ny");
```